# How to force set navigation bar width to automatically ?

Tags: html, css

I want to my nav-bar width fit automatically.

### Here is part of my CSS

```
#nav-bar {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

### Here is my whole working code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogBxxN

### Here is my result

When I adjust the width to 900, this is what I see

[image]

When I adjust the width to 1000, this is what I see

[image]

As you can see, none of them give me the best result.

I was wondering maybe some CSS expert can help me fixing this issue.

Comment: You're using padding to control the width of your buttons, but in reality you want to control the width by a percent and not the padding, that way they will fill evenly across no matter the nav-bar width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you using flexbox

```
#nav-bar ul {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
float: left;
display:flex;
flex-direction:row;
}
#nav-bar li {
text-align: center;
float: left;
order:1;
flex-grow:1;
```

}

by the way you are styling the list items twice, with .inline li and #nav-bar li

### [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogBxxN)

Comment: Do you mind fix my [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogBxxN) and save it as your version. So I see your result in there. If it's work, I'll make sure to accept it.

Comment: Also, because this is using flexbox, it will automatically size the list items to fit the space, try adding longer text to one.

Comment: how's come it's work on the Codepen, and on my local, it looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/56134944/break%20on%20local.JPG). I copied the whole CSS from there. Any idea ?

Comment: Its hard to say without the live site, but my guess is that part of the code is getting over written by something else.  Check the #nav-bar ul and make sure display is set to flex.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding `white-space: nowrap;` to your `ul` element and only use `display: inline-block;` on your `li` elements as opposed to the `float: left;` that is there.

Example:
http://codepen.io/jessikwa/pen/YPNqpw

Comment: That's is not what I want. :(

Comment: `width:auto` is too long for me.

Comment: No, in your CSS you have `float: left` on your `li` element.. Can you describe the desired outcome a little more clearly?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. [HERE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogBxxN) @Justin Breiland got it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `table` layout:

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#nav-bar ul {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  display:table;
  white-space:nowrap;
  text-align:center;
}
#nav-bar li  { display:table-cell; }
#nav-bar li a{
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  background:#eee; /*put back your gradients here */
  line-height: 40px;
  height: 41px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color:#000;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav-bar">
  <ul class="inline">
    <li><a href="#Europe">Europe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Asia">Asia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#North America">North America</a></li>
    <li><a href="#Oceania">Oceania</a></li>
    <li><a href="#South America">South America</a></li>
    <li><a href="#South America">South America</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

That's it.

Answer (score -1):

Using your current code, in your CSS:

```
.inline li {
    width: 16.666%;} // 100 divided by number of items

#nav-bar li a {
    padding: 0;} // remove the padding
```

Comment: Genius ! I didn't know that.